# Showing that $\bigcap_{x\in(1,10)} [0, x)=[0, 1]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that

$$\bigcap_{a\in(1,10)} [0, a)=[0, 1].$$

I know how to prove that $\text{RHS}\subseteq\text{LHS}$ but I am struggling with the other direction.

My attempt:

Let $x\in\text{LHS}$. This means for all $a\in(1, 10)$, $0\le x<a$...

I am trying to find a way to show that $0\le x\le 1$ to complete the proof. All I know is that for all $a\in (1, 10)$, $a>1$. How do I proceed?

Comment: Did you prove that $x\ge 0$? That's the easy part. The interesting part is to prove that $x\le 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could proceed by contradiction.

If $\,x>1\,,\,$ for $\,a=\min\{x,9\}\in(1,10)\,,\,$ you would get $\,0\leqslant x<a\leqslant x\,$ which is a contradiction.
Hence, $\,x\not>1\,,\,$ that is, $\,x\leqslant1\,.$